# Wordpress visual - no linebreaks being recognised

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. I've created a theme, and everything is fine with the exception of when I create a post in the visual editor. For me, it's fine, but most of the users don't know HTML so can't really go in and edit code.

In the element inspector (Chrome), the article comes up like this:

"Text...

More text..."

So when I look at it in Wordpress' Visual editor, everything looks fine, but on the page itself, it looks like this:

"Text...  More text..."

Any ideas on what HTML/CSS would recognise the line breaks like that, or how to add

tags to automatically create within the Visual editor?

Thanks!

Comment: Would `<pre>` work? Else, you'd probably need something to transform `\r\n` (line breaks) to `<br />`.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a yucky habit of removing break tags. What I do on all my sites so I don't even have to think about this issue is install the plugin TinyMCE advanced http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tinymce-advanced/ . In it's settings you will see a checkbox at the bottom that says "Stop removing the `<p>` and `<br />` tags when saving and show them in the HTML editor". Just make sure that is checked. This way, when someone is in the visual editor and they go to the next line, the break will be created and will always be reflected in the HTML editor and the live page.